# JButton not working with actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make the applet display the menu choices but the `JButton` doesn't seem to want to work with the `ActionListener`. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. BTW: I'm using another public class called `Lab4` with this, so the `JButton` is "order", the lists are `MyLists`, and `grill` is a `JCheckBox`. Also `label9` is the top `JLabel` on the `JFrame` on the right. [JApplet that isn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsdLn.png)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab5 extends Lab4 implements ActionListener{

    public void init(){
        super.init();
        order.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {    System.out.println(" At Method action Performed");
         String whichButton = e.getActionCommand();
         if (whichButton.equals("Place Order"))  displayData();

         validate();
    }
    public void displayData(){
         System.out.println(" At Method Display Data");
        String sandwich,drink,side,size;
        boolean grilled;
            sandwich = (String) sandwichlist.getSelectedValue();
            drink = (String) drinklist.getSelectedValue();
            side = (String) sidelist.getSelectedValue();
            size = (String) myChoice.getSelectedItem();
            grilled = grill.isSelected();
        label9.setText(size + grilled + sandwich + side +"with" + drink);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to also post the source for `Lab4`

Comment: You should also describe what 'doesn't want to work' means - what you expect to happen, what actually happens, etc.

Comment: Did you use your preferred debugger to check what `e.getActionCommand()` returned when you pressed the button?

Comment: *"..the top `JLabel` on the `JFrame` on the right"* conflicts with *"JApplet that isn't working"*. An app. is normally either a `JFrame` or a `JApplet` but not both (it **can** be a hybrid applet/application, but I doubt that is the case here). So which is it? OK forget that, but rather than post the code for `Lab4` as suggested by @MadProgrammer, I'm going to raise the bar and suggest to post a [mcve]. Make sure that we can reproduce whatever it is you see on compilation or running the code.

Comment: I think the fun and merit of @MadProgrammer 's suggestion is that `Lab4` will end up being a subclass of `Lab3`.

Comment: You might find [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/), [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) interesting

Comment: @pvg *"`Lab4` will end up being a subclass of `Lab3`"* The extant code tells the casual observer that `Lab4` **is** a sub-class of `Lab3`. So *..well duh!* But the point is that  `Lab3` might extend `Lab2`, which might in turn import 3 other custom classes. An MCVE OTOH should include all code needed to compile and run it, and see the problem, which is why there are two close reasons that include mention of 'no MCVE'.

Comment: BTW @MadProgrammer. Great advice, Did you check out the screenshot? I did not edit it into the question simply because compilable code would help much more at the moment. OTOH, it shows an applet on the left, and what appears to be a frame on the right. This suggests to me that the OP ***might*** be launching a frame from applet code. But I'd want to see an MCVE before thinking too much more about what the code actually doing.

Comment: As an aside @pvg *"You should also describe what 'doesn't want to work' means - what you expect to happen, what actually happens, etc."* that is an excellent idea, and is too often overlooked by people asking for advice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The extant code does not tell the casual observer anything of the sort. Also, it was a joke.

Comment: @pvg Oh, I misread the numbers. :P